# Cloud Firestore returns false when getting an existing document

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, document

I'm trying to retrieve a document by a specific id passed by parameter and I'm 100% sure the document exists but Firestore says the opposite.

Here's the code of my function

```
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    private fun retrieveUsersFromParticipantsId(participant: String) {
    db.collection("Usuarios").document(participant).get().addOnCompleteListener {
        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            val user = it.result.toObject(User::class.java)
            participantsArray.add(user!!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, how exactly is this code executing in a way that differs from what you expect?

Comment: Does your `addOnCompleteListener` get called? If so, what is the value of `it`?

Comment: I was calling this method in a for-each inside an ArrayList. Somehow the function didn't work properly when being called from the loop so I decided to try it outside, in a single call and it worked. Maybe I'm an ignorant but seems kind of strange to me.